# 301 redirect any page to one specific page

Tags: .htaccess

IS there a way with just htaccess 301 redirect to redirect any page on a domain to a specific page on another domain.

eg. I was `domain.com/index.html` and `domain.com/contact.html` to both redirect to `newsite.com/index.html`

But I am wanting to do this without having to list each of the pages specifically.

can my 301 redirect be just something like

```
301 * http://newsite.com/index.html
```

or how should it be set up. Unfortunately I don't have access to mod rewrite so I cant use mod rewrite to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is possible -- instead of mod_rewrite you need to use mod_alias (which has more chances to be enabled).

This one will redirect **everything** to `index.html` on `newsite.com/`

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)$ http://newsite.com/index.html
```

This one will redirect **everything** to the same path but on another domain: (e.g. `oldsite.com/meow.php` => `newsite.com/meow.php`)

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1
```

Answer (score 2):

Had an issue similar to this using wordpress and trying to remove all .asp extensions from pages, this worked pasted at the top of my .htaccess file

```
## 301 Redirects
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.asp$ $1? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```